# Sora R3000 STI shifters compatibility

Tags: drivetrain

Are the new Sora R3000 STI shifters compatible with dura ace 7700 brakes and derailleurs?

Thanks

Comment: I wish I knew this answer. I haven't done anything geeky/desperate with them yet. FD-R3000 uses an iteration of their newer-school extra long upper pivot arm design with adjustable anchor position, so I've been assuming the front shifting is not backwards compatible for R3000. RD-R3000 however doesn't look like the newer design that the 11-speed groups plus RD-4700 use. So I don't know but suspect the front is a no-go.

Comment: Brakes should, its just pulling a cable. Derailleurs, probably, since its the shifter that does the ratcheting / ratios (the RD is essentially a chainguide on a spring)

Comment: @devilfish17 Sorry, wrong on both counts. Brakes have a leverage ratio at both the lever and caliper, these must match. Yes, shifters pull the cable and do the indexing, but derailleurs have a movement ratio (distance lateral motion per length cable pulled) that again has to match what the shifter is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

The rear shifter is compatible with the 7700. The front 2x is only compatible with R3000 2x because of how it pulls the cable. If you're running a triple that you can interchange parts.